# Having trouble looping arguments with multiples of three. (newb)

Tags: java

The goal of this program is to run arguments such as "K6V3  20.2 17.4" and use the Weather class to calculate the windchill based on the last 2 numeric arguments and use the first argument as the shorthand name for the area. Im running into a problem when the program is given args in multiples of three, such as "K6V3  20.2 17.4 KCHO  40.0 10.0" Im not sure how to get the loop to restart after the third arg.  My program will take the first three args and display the correct information, but it will just repeat that information for the second three args. Here is my code so far, HELP!?!?!

```
public class ChillMapper {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double ICAO;
        double t;
        double v;
        double windChill;

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length / 3; i++) {
            if (args.length % 3 == 0) {
                ICAO = Text.toDouble(args[0]);
                t = Text.toDouble(args[1]);
                v = Text.toDouble(args[2]);
                windChill = Weather.windChillNA(t, v);
                Map.setTemperature(args[i], windChill);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably simpler to write the loop this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i+=3)
{
    ICAO = Text.toDouble(args[i+0]);
    t = Text.toDouble(args[i+1]);
    v = Text.toDouble(args[i+2]);
    windChill = Weather.windChillNA(t,v);
    Map.setTemperature(ICAO,windChill);
}
```

Instead of checking every time if `i%3==0`, you jump by steps of 3. (You better have some checks that the argument length itself is *multiple of* 3, I leave that to you as an exercise). Then you take the arguments at index i, i+1, i+2 respectively.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by checking if the argument length is 3? Isn't that what my if statement did?

Comment: It is just to protect yourself of an "out of bounds exception" if the program is called with a wrong number of arguments, like for example with "K6V3 20.2 17.4 KCHO 40.0" (5 arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You have the array indexes hardcoded. Use variable 'i' instead:

```
public class ChillMapper
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double ICAO;
    double t;
    double v;
    double windChill;

   int i = 0;
   if (args.length % 3 == 0)
   {
      while (i < args.length)
      {
         ICAO = Text.toDouble(args[i]);
         t = Text.toDouble(args[++i]);
         v = Text.toDouble(args[++i]);
         windChill = Weather.windChillNA(t,v);
         Map.setTemperature(args[i],windChill);
     }
   }
 }
}
```